# React issue with setting state after fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a form which I'd like to load with data on initial load.

I've setup did Mount to call my function fetchClaims.  I receive back the result and I'm able to console log it.  What I can't do is update my state with it so that I can then use it in my form.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.onInit(this.props);
}

onInit = props =>
  props
    .fetchClaims()
    .then(results => console.log('results = ' + JSON.stringify(results)))
    .then(claims => this.setState({ results }))
    .then(results =>
      console.log('results state = ' + JSON.stringify(this.state)),
    );
```

The resulting data looks like

```
results = {
  type: 'CLAIMS_FETCHED',
  claims: [
    {
      _id: '5b0d5b7f035a00f06003e6b8',
      claimID: '123456',
      claimDate: '2018-05-14T00:00:00.000Z',
      carrier: 'BCBS NJ',
    },
  ],
};
```

and the state looks like

```
state = {
  data: { email: '' },
  loading: false,
  errors: {},
  fromdate: '',
  todate: '',
  claims: {},
  results: {},
};
```

I'd like to populate the Claims array into the claims in state and then map over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try returning the value after the first console log and fix the parameter name when setting the state.

```
onInit = props => props.fetchClaims()
    .then(results => {
        console.log("results = " + JSON.stringify(results));
        return results;
    })
    .then(results => this.setState({ claims: results.claims }))
    .then(() => console.log("results state = " + JSON.stringify(this.state)));
```

Comment: thank you, that worked.  Now that I have this in my state, I believe I can "map" it.  Is that Correct?

Comment: @Reacting that's correct, you can map it in your render function.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code, try this:

```
onInit = props => props.fetchClaims()
 .then(results =>  {
  console.log("results = " + JSON.stringify(results))
  this.setState( { results }, () => console.log("results state = " + JSON.stringify(this.state) ))
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this u may get

```
onInit = props => props.fetchClaims()
           .then(
             res =>res.json() )
           .then(results => this.setState({results }, () 
 => console.log('results ', results )))
```